How to make a website online when the case is like the one below?
Don't understand how to deploy
Hello, I'm a beginner who is learning backend with .net and front end with react js,
For example I deploy backend code and sql database in cloud like Azure. Can I deploy the front end in Vercel but the front end code has an API connection, can this be done?

Yes, it can be done
It is usually the standard these days with the advent of Single Page Applications
